# How do you toggle check marks on an HTML unordered list?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a list of items out of which user can choose any one item.

I have this code till now -

```js
var state = 0;

function selectLI(element) {
  if (state == 0) {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "<span class='liTick'>&#10004;</span>";
    state = 1;
  } else {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('checklistLI');
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
      var els = ele[i].getElementsByClassName(".liTick");
      els.item(0).style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="checklist">
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 1</li>
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

What the code is supposed to do is first generate a tick and remove it if user chooses another time and generate a tick on that item instead. The first tick generates fine but it keeps giving me an error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

when I try to remove the first tick and generate second one.

I could simply just use radio buttons but I don’t want that kind of UI.

Comment: This seems a lot more complicated for what it's actually doing. Why don't you just put the ticks there by default, and when clicking on the relevant `li` you just toggle a hidden class (which has `display: none;`) on the tick rather than this seemingly excessive code?

Comment: I agree but I couldn't think of any other logic hence this code.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is a trigger phrase (though it *is* actually explained what it is, both before and after). It could be left out without loss of information. It would also be better to add some kind of [lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_paragraph) (so it doesn't *look* like a code dump (it isn't)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues making it so your code doesn't hide the tick:

1. You've included a `.` in the class name when calling `getElementsByClassName`, but the class name doesn't actually have a dot in it.
2. You're looping through all the `li` elements, but only some of them have a `liTick` inside them; you're not allowing for the possibility you didn't find one.

The minimal fix is:

```
var els = ele[i].getElementsByClassName("liTick");
// No `.` here −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
if (els[0]) { // <== Make sure there is one
  els[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

Or in really up-to-date environments, you could use optional chaining:

```
var els = ele[i].getElementsByClassName("liTick");
els[0]?.style.display = "none";
```

**But**, I wouldn't do that, because it's just hiding the tick. The be consistent, if you're *adding* a tick, you should *remove* (not just hide) it.

Separately, you have only one state flag, but there are multiple elements. I'm going to assume they should be independently "tick"-able. For that, we want to base our decision on whether the element already has a tick in it.

Also, avoid using `innerHTML` (and in particular avoid `.innerHTML = .innerHTML + "x"`). Instead, just insert what you need.

Here's an example:

```js
function selectLI(element) {
    const tick = element.querySelector(".liTick");
    if (tick) {
        // Remove the tick
        tick.remove(); // In modern environments
        // Or: tick.parentNode.removeChild(tick); // In older environments
    } else {
        // Add the tick
        element.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforeend",
            "<span class='liTick'>&#10004;</span>"
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="checklist">
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 1</li>
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Or if you wanted only **one** item to be allowed to have a tick:

```js
function selectLI(element) {
    const tick = element.querySelector(".liTick");
    if (tick) {
        // Remove the tick
        tick.remove(); // In modern environments
        // Or: tick.parentNode.removeChild(tick); // In older environments
    } else {
        // Remove any other tick
        const other = document.querySelector(".checklistLI .liTick");
        if (other) {
            other.remove(); // Or, again, the longer form in old environments
        }
        // Add the tick to this element
        element.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforeend",
            "<span class='liTick'>&#10004;</span>"
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="checklist">
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 1</li>
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

---

Note that this is not *accessible* to people using assistive technologies. Consider using a `<input type="checkbox">` instead.

Comment: This answer partially answers my question because originally I wanted to create that if one li is clicked then if tick exists in other lis, it should get removed. But thanks for answering

Comment: @ArchitGargi - I've added an example of doing that, too.

Comment: Thank you it works but unfortunately before you someone else answered my question correctly

Comment: @ArchitGargi - All due respect, I also answered the question "correctly" in the first part of the answer above, before showing another way to do what I thought you wanted to do. But if you found the other answer more useful, that's absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes sorry I was not clear with the question, technically you answered my question correctly

Answer (score 2):

As [@Andy Holmes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477407/andy-holmes) suggested in a comment:

> This seems a lot more complicated for what it's actually doing. Why
> don't you just put the ticks there by default, and when clicking on
> the relevant `li` you just toggle a hidden class (which has `display: none;`) on the tick rather than this seemingly excessive code?

##### HTML

```html
<ul class="checklist">
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 1 <span class='liTick hidden'>&#10004;</span></li>
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 2 <span class='liTick hidden'>&#10004;</span></li>
  <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this)">item 3 <span class='liTick hidden'>&#10004;</span></li>
</ul>
```

##### CSS

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

##### JS

```js
function selectLI(element) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".checklistLI").forEach(function (el) {
    el.getElementsByClassName("liTick").item(0).classList.add("hidden");
  });

  element.getElementsByClassName("liTick").item(0).classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

##### Demo

[checklist](https://codepen.io/theAccountant/pen/mdqoEMd)

Comment: Nicely implemented from my comment ;) Could make it _slightly_ cleaner by using a class called `.hidden` rather than `.d-none` - less special characters and more descriptive when scanning through :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes I've done so as requested. Thank you for the suggestion.✌

Answer (score 1):

I will offer another option, where I only add or remove `active` class, and the check mark appears without unnecessary html or manipulation with DOM:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.checklistLI').forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = () => {
    el.closest('.checklist').querySelectorAll('.checklistLI').forEach(li => {
       li.isSameNode(el) ? li.classList.toggle('active') : li.classList.remove('active');
    })
  }
})
```

```css
li:after{
  content: '✔';
  opacity: 0;
}

li.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

li {
  /* optional */
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checklist">
  <li class="checklistLI">item 1</li>
  <li class="checklistLI">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution, it's working!

```
<ul class="checklist">
    <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this, 1)">item 1</li>
    <li class="checklistLI" onclick="selectLI(this, 2)">item 2</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var state1 = 0;
    var state2 = 0;

    function selectLI(element, flag) {
        if (flag === 1) {
            if (state1 === 0) {
                element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "<span class='liTick'>&#10004;</span>";
                state1 = 1;
            } else {
                element.innerHTML = 'item 1';
                state1 = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (state2 === 0) {
                element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "<span class='liTick'>&#10004;</span>";
                state2 = 1;
            } else {
                element.innerHTML = 'item 2';
                state2 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This answer unfortunately doesn't answer my question correctly. I don't want to have the dependency of adding numbers to each li's called function because the lis will be dynamically created.